# Sublime 3 Find in Files function shows no details

Tags: sublimetext3

I use Sublime3 "Find in Files" function to search a string in a log file. It only shows XXX matches in 1 file, but not shows details. 
My log file is a little big, about 5M and about 60000 lines. if I delete the content to 1000 lines, the "Find in Files" function work find. 
I want to know if Sublime3 could search such big file, or how to search in such file.
I also try change the formate of the log file, it not works. It's seems Sublime only can search little file.

```
Searching 1 file for "AT      : AT" (regex)
/Volumes/BBB/log/log/Test2.txt:
     <binary>
 8897 matches in 1 file
```

Comment: It's not the size of the file, it's because Sublime thinks that it's a binary file; it can search such files but it won't show output in the find panel. What happens when you try to just open that file for editing, does it open as expected?

Comment: Thanks. I find some chars in the log file is not UTF-8, this cause Sublime can't show the result. Other editors, such as Emeditor, BBEdit can show the result. Maybe Sublime should fix this kind of issue.

Comment: It can edit the file in general; if you open it and it shows you the contents as hexidecimal, you can use `File > Reopen with encoding` to tell it that it should be using e.g. UTF-8. Possibly if you open the file that way, Find in Files will be able to show you the results, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Turning off `enable_hexadecimal_encoding` (it's on by default) **may** also help; I haven't tried.

Comment: I find below code cause Sublime canon't search. I spend lots of time to find this error encoding. Does it has a quick way to find this kind of chars?     Error encoding chars-->     code:I�۶

Comment: Turning off enable_hexadecimal_encoding，not help for this issue. I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

if file contain non UTF-8 encoded characters, the sublime will take it as binary file, so you should delete invalid characters, everything will be ok.